# update-manager doesn't request PW - just NOOPs

Tags: update-manager, sudo

I upgraded to Maverick and now I never get the password dialog that 10.04 had for installing packages - it just NOOPs from the GUI. Ran update-manager with user privileges from terminal and no error output.

I understand that 10.10 now uses APT.  Is there a simple fix in the policy mods to enable requesting confirmation of SU privileges as it did in 10.04?

Comment: Do you mean NOOP as in 0x90? Please clarify/edit this to get better answers, it's quite witty but not entirely appropriate here. :-) Even though I understand what a NOP is, I'm not sure what "just NOOPs from the GUI" means.

Comment: THX - no operation, e.g., no error & terminates.  I've never seen a GUI with an instruction set ;-)

Comment: NOP means it does nothing, quitting *is* an operation. Can you perform an upgrade by doing `sudo apt-get upgrade` in a terminal?

Comment: 0 upgraded, 0 newly installed, 0 to remove and 0 not upgraded.  Please drop the professorial tone.  You have not idea whom you are aiding.

Comment: The GUI does not terminate.

Comment: I'm sorry you took my tone badly, I didn't mean to sound condescending.

Answer (score 2):

It looks like you're experiencing a *valid* bug. This behaviour isn't easily explainable by anything you might have done, it looks like it's simply an error in 'update-manager'.

Please report your bug to  [update-manager in Ubuntu](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/update-manager/). Include all of the steps to replicate the problem on your system. The Ubuntu Wiki has a very nice   [guide on how to report bugs](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/ReportingBugs).

In the meantime, it looks like you have to manually update by doing `sudo apt-get upgrade` in a Terminal.